# Setup version vs Module Version

Tags: module, magento2.2.6, third-party-plugin

How to check the third party plugin version without any code in Magento 2?

Also, please let me know what exactly is Setup version and Module version.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @RohanHapani I have two questions, 1. What are the methods to check the plugin version in Magento? 2. What is the difference between Setup version and Module version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Follow below path for check module Setup version and Module Version:**

**Setup version:** setup_version is your module’s database schema version.

Go to the module.xml file in module and find "setup_version"

**File path:** app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/module.xml

> setup_version="1.1.4"

**Module Version:** version lists the version of the component.

Go to the composer.json file in module root directory and find "version"

**File path:** app/code/Namespace/Module/composer.json

> "version": "1.1.4",

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help me to understand the difference between Setup version and Module version?

Comment: setup_version => setup_version is your module’s database schema version.

version=> version lists the version of the component.